# How do I get column names of a model created in PyCaret

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, pycaret

I am trying to create a PyCaret Model

```
# load dataset
from pycaret.datasets import get_data
insurance = get_data('insurance')

# init environment
from pycaret.regression import *

r1 = setup(insurance, target = 'charges', session_id = 123,
           normalize = True,
           polynomial_features = True,
           bin_numeric_features= ['age', 'bmi'])
```

I see 55 columns are now created. How do I get column names of PyCaret Model

Answer (score 0):

## train a model

```
lr = create_model('lr')
```

#get model column names

```
lr.feature_names_in_
```